# What is my error is setting this up? This Sub runs perfectly in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

A "Runtime Error 9, Subscript Out of Range" is received on the Set wb1 line.  This similar structure runs fine in a different workbook without error.

My goal is to copy a cell from the Source document into te Destination document.

```
Sub CopySheetsl()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("C:\Test\DST.xlsm")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Source.xlsx")

    wb1.Sheets("SourceNamedSheet").Range("A1") = wb.Sheets("DestinationNamedSheet").Range("A1").Value

    wb1.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the new workbook have sheets named "SourceNamedSheet" and "DestinationNamedSheet"?

Comment: Yes those sheets are named.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on the `Set wb1` line, and not the next?

Comment: @t.mo is "C:\Test\DST.xlsm" the workbook with this code in it ? if it is, you can use `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`, If not where is this `Sub CopySheetsl` located ? a third workbook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a more robust approach to workbooks handling you may want to use the following `GetOrSetWorkbook()` function:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetOrSetWorkbook(wbName As String) As Workbook        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOrSetWorkbook = Workbooks(GetNameOnly(wbName)) '<--| check if a workbook with given name is already open
    If GetOrSetWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set GetOrSetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(wbName) '<--| if no workbook open with given name then try opening it with full given path
End Function
```

which uses the following *helper* `GetNameOnly()` function:

```
Function GetNameOnly(pathStrng As String) As String
    Dim iSlash As Long

    iSlash = InStrRev(pathStrng, "\")
    If iSlash > 0 Then
        GetNameOnly = Mid(pathStrng, iSlash + 1, Len(pathStrng))
    Else
        GetNameOnly = pathStrng
    End If
End Function
```

so that a possible use of it could be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetsl()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wb = GetOrSetWorkbook("C:\Test\DST.xlsm") '<--| try getting "C:\Test\DST.xlsm"
    If wb Is Nothing Then '<--| if unsuccessful...
        '... code to handle C:\Test\DST.xlsm workbook error, like:
        MsgBox "Couldn't find 'C:\Test\DST.xlsm' !", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    End If

    Set wb1 = GetOrSetWorkbook("C:\Test\Source.xlsx") '<--| try getting "C:\Test\Source.xlsx
    If wb Is Nothing Then '<--| if unsuccessful...
        '... code to handle 'C:\Test\Source.xlsx' workbook error, like:
        MsgBox "Couldn't find 'C:\Test\Source.xlsx'!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    End If


    'here goes rest of the code to be executed once all necessary workbooks have been properly set
    wb1.Sheets("SourceNamedSheet").Range("A1") = wb.Sheets("DestinationNamedSheet").Range("A1").Value

    wb1.Close
End Sub
```

of course a very similar *GetOrSet* approach can be assumed with worksheets, too...

Comment: @t.mo, did you get through it?

Comment: @t.mo, it'd be nice of you to give proper feedback to people trying helping you

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I did some additional reading after your post and used the GetorSetWorkbook() and it worked great.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to see it really helped. Thanks for accepting the answer. Good coding!

Answer (score 2):

If `DST.xlsm` is open already then

`Set wb = Workbooks("DST.xlsm")`

ElseIf you need to open `DST.xlsm`

`Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\DST.xlsm")`